# How can I get the ActivatedRoute in a component that is not involved with routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How can I get the ActivatedRoute in a component that is not involved with routing?

I tried like this:

```
constructor(
  private _route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
  this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {

    console.log(params['param1'], params['param2']);

  });

}
```

It logs `undefined, undefined`.

Comment: Your code should be fine though. You sure you've got param1 and param2 in your url?

Comment: Yup. And I put this same code in another component that is the router outlet, and it traced out my parameters, as expected, but it does it after this code runs.

Comment: Does it work if you just pass params, without a type definition? Just lile params => {...}

Comment: Tried your suggestion. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Type declarations don't have any effect at runtime